# Expression trees for code which doesn't type check

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Is it possible to construct an expression tree in .NET 3.5 from code like

```
Expression expr = () => (true + new object())
```

? It seems to be impossible, since "[A compiler-generated expression tree is always rooted in a node of type Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)", but I may be missing something.

Obviously, such a tree can be constructed manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not obvious that such a tree can be constructed manually. The expression the tree is representing is type-checked as it is being constructed. As such, what you ask is not possible and the answer is no.